# How to permanently change the colour of the cell using conditional formation VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, encoding, formatting

I would like to change the colour of the cells based on a rule permanently. I used conditional formating for top 2 values in each of my columns. It was supposed to change the colour of top 2 cells in red and it did it, but after that I needed to copy and paste only the colour of the cells not the actual formula behind the colour. When I check the format of the cell, it says that there is no background colour. I need to copy these colours and paste them on another range of sells, ONLY the colours. I asked a friend for a macro and this is what he created for me, but it does the same job as conditional formating:

```
Sub SortColoredCells()
    Dim rng2 As Range
    For Each rng2 In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns
        c_name = GetColumnLetter(rng2.Cells.Column)
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Sort.SortFields.Add(Range(c_name & "2:" & c_name & "1000"), _
            xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Sort
            .SetRange Range(c_name & "1:" & c_name & "1000")
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Thank you for you help!

Comment: "I would like to change the colour of the cells based on **a rule** permanently." what is that **rule**?

Comment: I would like to colour in red the top 2 values of each column independantly. I am not very good at programming so I would love to hear your thoughts. Thank you!

Comment: Then I need to copy only the colours, but by conditional formating I cant paste only colours as I can when I colour the cells manually.

Comment: copy colors to where?

Comment: I am doing my dissertation and I need to apply momentum strategy. So I need to copy the coloured cells and paste them to another range of data one period ahead, which will colour the cells of the second data set without changing their values.

Comment: what you are saying does not make sense, you don't need to copy range to change the color of another range. You need to provide sample data or screen shots of what you want to do exactly, and I am sure your question will be tagged as unclear and will be deleted since you are new and you have not followed the rules for how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I understand that my question may be a bit unclear. So basically what I need is just to colour the top 2 cells in each column red and then only paste the colours to another data set. With conditional formating it is not possible, when I change the colours of the cells manually, then I am able to paste ony the colours. Please give me some advices because I really tried every option.

Answer (score 0):

This code will change the top 2 rows color to red. Right click on the sheet tab, select `view code` and then paste it there and hit F5 to run the code:

```
       Sub main()

    'loop thru columns
    For i = 1 To UsedRange.Columns.Count

        'look for top values in each column cell by cell
        Set Rng = Sheets("Ranked").UsedRange.Columns(i).Cells

        'reset parameters
        a = 0 'top 1 value
        b = 0 '2nd top value
        Set cella = Nothing
        Set cellb = Nothing

        For Each cell In Rng
            If IsNumeric(cell) = True Then
                If cell.Value > b Then
                    If cell.Value > a Then
                       b = a
                        Set cellb = cella
                        a = cell.Value
                        Set cella = cell
                    Else
                        b = cell.Value
                        Set cellb = cell
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next cell

        'color the cells
        If Not cella Is Nothing Then cella.Interior.Color = vbRed
        If Not cellb Is Nothing Then cellb.Interior.Color = vbRed
    Next i
End Sub
```

**output**
[image]